# Criar um fluxograma via web (python) utlizando dados de uma linha de um Dataset

Tags: python, aplicação-web, dataset

Preciso criar um fluxograma na web (mais ou menos como na imagem abaixo) ,com setas que conectem estes quadros, e  também que possa "puxar" as informações de uma das linhas de um dataset, para então "copiar" cada dado de cada coluna do dataset para cada um dos quadros (no lugar das palavras Processo). 
   E que seja dinâmico, para após qualquer atualização dos dados eles também possam mudar na web.  
A linguagem de programação utilizada será python e tenho o conhecimento básico da linguagem.
Mas não faço ideia de como posso desenvolver isto via web? 
 O que sugerem que eu precise aprender para desenvolver algo assim?  
 Eu não tenho ideia se aprender Django ou Flask poderia me ajudar, se preciso aprender html,css...... Estou bem perdido pra identificar quais recursos preciso aprender para de fato realizar este desenvolvimento.

EM RESUMO, preciso saber como criar um fluxograma via web, no qual a inclusão e atualização de dados em cada quadro seja dinâmica com meu dataset, e não estática, com a linguagem python.

Ficaria muito grato se alguém tiver recomendações, dicas de como/onde começar, o que utilizar... obrigado desde já!!!

[image: Fluxograma objetivo]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Já passei por um problema similar na empresa onde trabalho e sei bem como você está se sentindo. O que recomendo que você veja e estudo logo de começo caso você não saiba e **banco de dados relacionais (SQL)**. Se souber bem como montar um banco de dados relacionado vai evitar qualquer tipo de problema futuro.

Acredito que o Flask não iria funcionar bem para o que você quer, ele fica melhor com aplicações básicas e não complexas. Para o que você está querendo a única coisa que vem em minha mente é o Django, ele foi desenvolvido para o que você está querendo fazer, com ele você consegue fazer um sistema ERP, CRM, de logística e etc. Com o Django você vai conseguir criar tabelas para o seu banco de dados e conecta-las por lá mesmo. Também vai consegui extrair, adicionar, deletar ou visualizar determinado dado de seu banco de dados (O famoso CRUD), logo após ter aprendido a fazer isso, você vai moldar os dados baseado no que você precisa, ai o limite é o céu e sua imaginação de como vai querer criar seu sistema.

Caso você seja iniciante no Python, recomendo que você estude um pouco de POO (Programação orientada a objetos) porque o Django é praticamente todo baseado em Objeto, e caso você não saiba pelo menos um pouco sobre isso, você pode ficar meio perdido e vai terminar desistindo de seu projeto.

## Resumo

Aprenda primeiro a criar um banco de dados consistente e lógico, logo em seguida estudo um pouco sobre POO e depois é cair de cabeça no Django.

Comment: Sua orientação sobre a utilização do Django, ao invés do Flask, e que de fato a utilização do Django é realmente válida para esse desenvolvimento foram de grande valia para mim, pois em meio a um vasto universo de possibilidades, é complicado iniciar um novo aprendizado e no final saber que foi em vão e não vai ser útil para este projeto. Muito obrigado por suas dicas, Vou investir no aprendizado de SQL, POO e Django.